# ODE with substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

"Solve the first order initial value problem

$x^2\frac{dy}{dx}+24-10xy+x^2y^2=0$

$y(1)=1$

by making the substitution $y=u^{-1}\frac{du}{dx}$"

First we derive $y$ to get

$y'=-u^{-2}u'+u^{-1}u''$

And then replace in the ODE to get to:

$(x^2)u''+(\frac{x^2}{u}u'-\frac{x^2}{u}-10x)u'+24u=0$

I could probably work this out using the Cauchy-Euler equation, but the $\frac{x^2}{u}u'$ term is stopping me from doing so. How can I continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Considering $$x^2y'+24-10xy+x^2y^2=0$$ start using $x\,y=z$ to make
$$x z'+(z-11) z+24=0$$ Work with $x(z)$ to make
$$\frac x {x'}+(z-11) z+24=0\implies \frac  {x'}x=-\frac 1 {z^2-11z+24}=-\frac 1 {(z-3)(z-8)}$$ which is separable. Now, partial fraction decomposition of the rhs and ... just finish.

Comment: How did you change $xz'$ to $\frac{x}{x'}$

Comment: $\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac 1 {\frac{dx}{dz}}$